# Excel – using multiple criteria in COUNTIFS function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I need to create a formula that counts the number of times there is an overdue date in column I, where the corresponding cell in column J is blank.

I enter a date in column H (date appointed). There is a formula to auto-fill column I (date due) which is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H6), " ", EDATE(H6,6))
```

I need to create a formula to count the number of dates in column I which are older than today but only if the corresponding cell in column J is blank.

I have tried:

```
=COUNTIFS(I6:I260,"<TODAY()",J6:J260,"<>"&"""")
```

but I suspect it is counting the auto-fill formula in column I.

Comment: Wait — do you want to count the rows where Column ``J`` is blank, or where it isn’t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

*Use this Array (CSE) formula, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.*

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($I$139:$I$145,IF({1;0},"","<"&TODAY()),$J$139:$J$145,""))}
```

**N.B.**

- IF function generates an array that resolves to something like this, `{"";">43510"}`.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: This works, but I'm curious why you didn't use the simpler formula: `=COUNTIFS($I$139:$I$145,"<"&TODAY(),$J$139:$J$145,"")` (non-array)

Comment: @fixer1234,, yeah this also works,, but while I was testing sometimes returns 7 so that I've wrapped with array ☺

Comment: Thank you everyone they were both really helpful examples. I really appreciate your assistance and time taken to help me. cheers

Comment: @Jevene,, glad to help you ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

You’re making two mistakes:

- When you say `"<TODAY()"`,
  you’re comparing the value (in Column `I`) to the *string* `TODAY()`. 
  So, for example,
  if you put the days of the week into Column `I` *as strings,*
  then `Monday`, `Thursday`, `Friday`, `Saturday` and `Sunday`
  will be seen as being `<` `TODAY()`,
  but `Tuesday` and `Wednesday` will not. 
  However, no actual date values will be treated as being `<` `TODAY()`.

  - Normally (e.g., if you do `IF(D1<S1,…)`),
    all dates are considered to be less than all strings. 
    However, for purposes of `COUNTIF`,
    dates are not considered to be less than, greater than, or equal to strings. 
    They just aren’t counted.  
    This does not appear to be documented.
  - The fact that the values in Column `I` are computed by a formula
    is not an issue.

  You need to say `"<"&TODAY()` to get the value of today’s date.
- When you have two double quotes in a row in a string constant,
  they act like one double quote character. 
  That’s confusing. 
  For example, if you say `"foo""bar"` in a formula,
  it evaluates to the string value `foo"bar`. 
  By the same rule, if you say `""""` in a formula,
  it evaluates to the string value `"`,
  and when you say `"<>"&""""`, it evaluates to `<>"`,
  so you are comparing the values in Column `J` to `"`.

  To check for values not being blank,
  you need to say `"<>"&""`, or simply `"<>"`,
  which is terribly non-intuitive.

  - A *slightly* clearer syntax is `=*`,
    which tests whether the value is a non-null string. 
    However, `<>` will count all cells that are not empty,
    while `=*` will not count cells that contain numbers or dates. 
    Since you don’t say what you have in Column `J`,
    I don’t know whether this is useful to you.

So the formula you want is

```
=COUNTIFS(I6:I20,"<"&TODAY(), J6:J20,"<>")
```

Note that this is *not* an array formula, so
it *does **not*** require <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

For example:

[image: spreadsheet snippet demonstrating the above formula]

- Row 6 counts because `I6` (February 11, 2019)
  is less than today (February 19, 2019) and `J6` (`foo`) is not blank.
- Rows 7-9 don’t count because they are blank in Column `J`.
- Row 10 doesn’t count because `I10` is blank. 
  (Ditto for Rows 15-20.)
- Rows 11 and 12 don’t count because `I11` (February 25, 2019)
  and `I12` (February 26, 2019) are greater than today’s date.
- Rows 13 and 14 because the dates in Column `I` are in the future
  ***and*** they are blank in Column `J`.

Comment: thanks Scott, appreciate your in-depth answer. It does help explain everything. Still new to learning excel formulas but love a challenge and am impressed by you all for your vast knowledge.